# asp.net mvc 5 как отобразить данные из Database View пользователю на странице

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Вопрос: нужно вывести данные пользователю из представления. В моей реализации выводит верное количество строк, но количество всегда 0, а название null.

Запрос на создание представления в БД

```
CREATE VIEW ProductOrderCountView AS
SELECT P.Name AS [Название продукта],
   dbo.funcOrderCountProduct(P.Id) AS [Количество заказов]
FROM Products AS P
```

Класс для представления

```
public class ProductOrderCountView
{
    [DisplayName("Название продукта")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Количество заказов")]
    public int Count { get; set; }

    public static List<ProductOrderCountView> LoadProductOrderViewCount()
    {
        BakeryContext context = new BakeryContext();
        var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<ProductOrderCountView>("SELECT * FROM ProductOrderCountView;").ToList();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Разметка представления

```
@using Bakery.Models.ForDBView
@model IEnumerable<Bakery.Models.ForDBView.ProductOrderCountView>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Статистика по количеству проданных продуктов";
}

<h2>Статистика по количеству проданных продуктов</h2>

<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Count)
    </th>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model.OrderBy(o => o.Count))
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Count)
        </td>
    </tr>

}
</table>
```

Comment: @AK modelItem не имеет свойства Name

Comment: `SELECT P.Name AS [Название продукта], dbo.funcOrderCountProduct(P.Id) AS [Количество заказов]` ==> `SELECT P.Name AS Name,
   dbo.funcOrderCountProduct(P.Id) AS Count`

Comment: @tym32167, спасибо, помогло. оформите как ответ, пожалуйста

Comment: готово, оформил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас названия столбцов не совпадают с названием полей в вашей модели. Измените столбцы в вашем запросе с

```
 ...SELECT P.Name AS [Название продукта], 
           dbo.funcOrderCountProduct(P.Id) AS [Количество заказов]...
```

на

```
...SELECT P.Name AS Name, 
          dbo.funcOrderCountProduct(P.Id) AS Count....
```