# Как выполнить данный SQL запрос в C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

```
SELECT 
    tr3.TimeStart, 
    tr1.Price as PriceStart, 
    tr2.Price as PriceFinish, 
    tr3.PriceHigh, 
    tr3.PriceLow,
    tr3.Volume 
FROM TradeFill as tr1, 
    TradeFill as tr2, (
    SELECT 
        FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.TimeAdded)/(1 * 1 * 1 * 1)) AS timekey, 
        min(t1.Id) as min_id,
        max(t1.Id) as max_id,
        min(t1.TimeAdded) as TimeStart, 
        max(t1.TimeAdded) as t_max,
        min(t1.Price) as PriceLow, 
        max(t1.Price) as PriceHigh,
        SUM(t1.Quantity) as Volume
    FROM 
        TradeFill as t1
    WHERE t1.TimeAdded BETWEEN "2018-01-01 00:00:00" AND "2018-08-10 23:59:59"
    GROUP BY timekey
) as tr3
WHERE tr1.Id = tr3.min_id 
    AND tr2.Id = tr3.max_id
```

Пробую так:

```
var tradeFill = DbContext.TradeFill.FromSql(query).ToList();
```

Выдает ошибку

```
The required column 'Id' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation
```

В TradeFill нет данных полей которые в SELECT

Как можно просто выполнить данный запрос или может как-то переписать в LINQ

Comment: `The required column 'Id' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation` - как то пробовали решить эту проблему?

Comment: @tym32167 Проблема в том что класс TradeFill не содержит данные поля которые в SELECT ... FROM. В данном классе есть много обязательных полей. Если даже проблему с Id решить, то другие поля просто так не решить

Comment: Если он не содержит нужные вам поля, зачем вы его используете? Используйте тот класс, который содержит нужные поля

Comment: @tym32167 Поля вычисляемые, они мне нужны. Но их нет в классе TradeFill , так как эти поля вычисляются с этой таблицы

Comment: у вас есть SQL запрос, что возвращает определенные столбцы. Если вы пытаетесь мапить их на класс, где этих столбцов нет, то вы не получаете данные, что запросили. Как вы с этим работать собрались? Или я не понял вашу проблему

Comment: @tym32167 я просто хочу выполнить данный запрос и получить результат любым способом

Comment: создайте класс с нужными полями и выполните запрос, записывая результат в новый класс

Comment: @Alexandr я создал такой класс, а как выполнить запрос? Вот главная проблема))

Comment: Как правильно настроить DbSet

Comment: @Barlukov вот тут я мучался с выводом представления https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/865923/asp-net-mvc-5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-database-view-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5  посмотрите на класс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите выполнить произвольный запрос, который вообще никак не связан с моделью, нужно вытащить из DbContext соединение и работать с ним напрямую через ADO.NET. Допустим, если используется база SQL Server, как-то так:

```
var connection = (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection) DbContext.Database.Connection;

if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
{
    connection.Open();
}

var dt = new DataTable();

//получаем результат запроса в DataTable...
using (var adapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ...", connection))
{
    adapter.Fill(dt);
}

//далее работаем с DataTable...
foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows)
{
  foreach (var item in dataRow.ItemArray)
  {
    Console.Write(item.ToString()+"; ");
  }
  Console.WriteLine();
}
```