# Как лучше организовать и хранить результат SQL-запроса

Tags: c#, sql

Мне нужно организовать выполнение произвольных SQL запросов в приложении, т.е пользователь вводит sql запрос и он выполняется, удобен ли для этого EF или лучше использовать стандартные средства типа

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Users";
    command.Connection = connection;
}
```

И далее нужно же как то сохранить результат выполнения, что для этого лучше использовать?

Comment: 1) а как Вы через EF будете писать SQL 2) куда Вы хотите сохранять результат

Comment: @Yaroslav Спасибо за ответ, я как раз и думаю, а как я могу писать в еф запросы, из расчета может я чего не знаю.)) А сохранить я хочу для 1) отображения 2) для записи в файл

Comment: Если запросы на выборку, то DataReader должен быть быстрее. Запросы на изменение данных делать через EF, не используя модель, вообще бессмысленное занятие. Так что да, делайте как вы написали. Сохранять можно в DataSet или dynamic. Но лучше в DataSet.

Comment: @Yaroslav Вообще EF вполне умеет [в raw sql](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework4.3/raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework.aspx)

Comment: @АлексейЛосев Спасибо за ответ, через мой вариант я могу и изменить данные, ибо это же практически чистый sql

Comment: @Vladimr Vladimirovoch, каждый раз писать результат в файл не лучшее решение

Comment: @A K, спасибо за просвещение, не знал о такой возможности

Comment: @Yaroslav такая вот задача, мне нужно писать в csv файл, но я хочу отображать с начала результат выполнения запроса, и езху потом если нужно жмем кнопку и сохраняем то, что видим в файл

Comment: @Vladimr Vladimirovoch, а потом что с этим файлом делать будете

Comment: _через мой вариант я могу и изменить данные, ибо это же практически чистый sql_ - а если пользователь напишет `drop database`?

Comment: @A K, а метод SqlQuery поддерживает все возможности SQL, то у меня уже когда то возникал вопрос и за не корректного обращению к View

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, отличное замечание)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov буду делать проверку,и переспрашивать,

Comment: @Vladimr Vladimirovoch, лучше делать на уровне доступа к БД, в ролях

Comment: Проверку чего? Собираетесь собственный парсер sql писать?.. Надеюсь, вы знаете о [dcl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_control_language) и ролях.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov парсер это долго, а так да про роли знаю, но не использовал их еще ,вот читаю про них,это конечно же выход

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework - это ORM, т.е. средство для установления соответствия между базами данных и объектно-ориентированным кодом для работы с ними. Вся суть ORM - это как раз меньше писать руками SQL. Если вам не нужен объектно-ориентированный код для доступа к данным, а нужен произвольный SQL запрос, естественно EF "не будет удобен" (да и просто не нужен). Он хоть и позволяет выполнять SQL-запросы, но только возвращающие объекты модели, а не произвольные. Используйте стандартные средства ADO.NET.

Хранить результаты можно в DataTable ([Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/868029/240512)).